# How to create a location history similar to the google location history with no internet

Tags: android, google-maps

I do not know how to create "google location history". how it can take my place while I do not have internet. anyone can give me one tutorial. thank you.

Comment: all you need is a device that has a GPS chip in it, everything else is the same

Comment: Thank you, But Google get my location when my device Off internet + GPRS.